# Python reshaping a np 4D array into a 2D array. Kaggle Image data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am trying to convert a 4D array into a 2D array for the use of sklearn SVM model but it gives me issues when I try to use the data in the model. 
So i get the data split into the train  and test data and then convert it into a np array like so.

```
#Train data
npXt = np.array(x_train)
npYt = np.array(y_train)
#Eval test data
npXT = np.array(x_test)
npYT = np.array(y_test)
```

Then I look at the shape like so

```
npXt.shape
```

Which gives me this,

```
(28709, 48, 48, 1)
```

I try to change it by doing this;

```
npXt.transpose((28709, 48, 48, 1)).reshape(np.prod(npXt.shape[:2]),-1)
```

But gives this error.

```
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2682876229f4> in <module>()
----> 1 npXt.transpose((28709, 48, 48, 1)).reshape(np.prod(npXt.shape[:2]),-1)

AxisError: axis 28709 is out of bounds for array of dimension 4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help with this

**UPDATE:**
Thank you for all the suggestions:
I tried it and there is a error like this:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (28709, 7)
```

So here is what I have fixed to get to this. What I think is the problem is that I am not reshaping the array right currently.
So I download the data like this and this works fine:

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = aiu.getKaggleData(file,numClass)
```

Which gives this as the result:

```
Creating Testing and Training datasets
Filling datasets
Transforming data to fit model's needs
Normalizing traing/testing datasets
Reshaping data
28709 train samples
3589 test samples
```

I expect this and this worked with another model that I built.
Next I build the SVM model like so:

```
clf = SVC(C=0.01, kernel='linear', decision_function_shape='ovo', probability=True)
```

Then convert the train and test data into np arrays like this

```
#Train data
npXt = np.array(x_train)
npYt = np.array(y_train)
#Eval test data
npXT = np.array(x_test)
npYT = np.array(y_test)
```

Then using what has been suggested

```
my_array = np.ones((28709, 48, 48, 1))
newXTrain = np.transpose( my_array ).reshape(np.prod(npXt.shape[:2]),-1)
print(newXTrain.shape)
print(npYt.shape)
```

Which gives me this:

```
(1378032, 48) #for data
(28709, 7)    #for lables
```

Then I try to train the model like so

```
clf.fit(newXTrain,npYt)
```

Which gives me this

```
 raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
 ValueError: bad input shape (28709, 7)
```

Thank you for all your help so far

I have even tried this but still gives an error:

```
newXTrain = np.transpose( my_array ).reshape(np.prod(npXt.shape[:1]),-1)
```

That gives me this which looked promising.

```
(28709, 2304)
(28709, 7)
```

but gave the same error as `ValueError: bad input shape (28709, 7)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you transpose the array before the reshape 
however you are using transpose the wrong way.

it should be:

```
my_array = np.ones((28709, 48, 48, 1))
np.transpose( my_array ).reshape(np.prod(npXt.shape[:2]),-1)
```

if you pass a tuple to the transpose function it will interpret it as the new order of the indexes of the axes of your matrix. thus transposing the axis number 28709 doesn't make sense here.

If you want to reshape you may not need to transpose at all

Comment: You were right I just had to change parts of the shape and I got it to work thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the way you're using transpose. What should be passed as argument should be a list of positions, in your case integers between 0 and 3.

I guess you're trying to reverse the indexes of npXt, so maybe (3,2,1,0) should be put instead of (28709,48,48,1) as argument of the transpose function.